# How do I add regex conditionals inside of an awk command

Tags: bash, awk

Lets say I have multiple columns that may contain expressions that I want to select for if they do or do not match. How do I go about writing that awk expression?

Here is an example where I want to print columns only if certain fields get a match or not:

```
awk -v OFS=$'\t' -F $'t\' '($12 ~ /9\..[^b-z]/) || ($4 !~ /QA_[tT][eE][sS][tT]/) || ($4 !~ /ACC_Operator1/) || ($5 !~ /4CPP/) { print $8, $5, $4, $10, $6, $12}' filename
```

Running this gives me a

```
-bash: !~: event not found
```

Which I assume is a bash issue with using !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a typo, which is revealed by the syntax highlighter:

```
awk -v OFS=$'\t' -F $'t\' ...
                       ^ escaped single quote
```

This means that the opening quote of your awk command is actually closing the previous single quote.

Note that awk understands `\t`, so you can use `-v OFS='\t'`, rather than using `$'\t'`.